# Atlassian (Jira, Confluence) LDAP configuration

Tags: ldap, jira, config, openldap, confluence

I'm trying to configure User Directories for Atlassian products. OpenLDAP server is running, I have created a test user, groups etc. But I always get 'Test get user's memberships : Failed', have no idea why. I set up member overlay, here is the result of 'ldapsearch' command:

```
dn: uid=myaccount,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
memberOf: cn=atl,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
memberOf: cn=atl1,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
```

and here some extended output from 'ldapsearch':

```
dn: uid=myaccount,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
uid: myaccount
sn: Surname
givenName: Name
cn: myaccount
displayName: Name Surname
uidNumber: 10001
gidNumber: 10000
homeDirectory: /home/my

dn: cn=atl1,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: groupOfNames
cn: atl1
member: uid=myaccount,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com

dn: cn=atl,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: posixGroup
cn: atl
gidNumber: 10000
memberUid: uid=myaccount,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the LDAP settings page from Jira?

Comment: @scottysseus updated. But I tried different options...

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your base dn is wrong. Use it without the ou=People.
Add that ou=People to the Additional User DN and you can also add a ou=Groups(?) to the Additional Group DN